# Why is my variable being set equal to an incorrect value despite explicitly being set equal to the correct one in three different locations?

Tags: java, object, variables, stack

We have to write a program to simulate a bank for my Computer Science class. The program has three tellers, where customers can go. The third teller takes a stack of tasks when it's size is larger than 0. I instantiated the data values for this third teller in the data field as follows:

```
public static Task firstTask = new Task(916,3); 

public static  Teller teller3 = new Teller(new Customer(0,0,0),firstTask,3);
```

I then have a method that I wrote to make the teller start task in the teller class.

```
public  void startTask(Task arrivingTask) { 

    currentTask = arrivingTask; 

}
```

I call this with the same value of firstTask in the main method.

```
teller3.startTask(firstTask);
```

After this, I push onto the taskStack 2 new tasks.

```
    taskStack.push(new Task(910,12)); 
    taskStack.push(new Task(913,3));
```

I also instantiate the nextTask (the next task to arrive on the arrivals file).

```
Task nextTask = new Task(925,2);
```

I also have a print method in the teller class to print the task.

```
public void printTask() { 

    System.out.println("currentTask = (" + this.currentTask.getArrival() + "," + this.currentTask.getServiceTime() + ")");  

}
```

If I run this code: `teller3.printTask();` , the output is currentTask = (925,2).

I do not experiance this issue when doing something similar with customers. I am instantiating these values in the data field, and doing things such as taskStack.push(n), where n = new Task(910,12). Everything else in my code works perfectly, except for this.

Later on in the code, event5, the event which handles task completion, contains the following code pertaining to the task, and nothing else.

```
firstTask.printTask(); 

    if (taskStack.getSize() > 0) { 
        System.out.println(currentTime); 

        firstTask = taskStack.pop(); 
        teller3.startTask(firstTask);
        Event newEvent = new Event(currentTime + 
teller3.T1ServiceTime(),5); 

        Elist.insert(newEvent); 
        teller3.isBusy = true;
        firstTask.printTask(); 
    }
```

Here, you can see that I did two things. I first printed the task. The task always prints as the value I assigned earlier to nextTask, which I never in my program declare as firstTask. When the taskStack is larger than 0, I set the firstTask equal to taskStack.pop(). It actually does pop the value, but it doesn't change the value of firstTask. I know from the event list because a new event is added every for three minutes later. I print the task again after the if statement runs (which I know from the code it does run), and the firstTask does not change its value. Where should I go from here?

Comment: It's hard to follow your code all chopped up like that. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note: costumers are people who make or otherwise provide costumes.  The word you appear to be looking for is "customers".

Comment: Hello, I am sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow. Should I delete the question for now and edit it with that once I create it? The problem is that there are multiple classes. I believe it is a confusing concept. The reason why I wrote it that way was so that I could explain in between the requirements of the program and the methods in the classes else where so that the reader doesn't have to look at too much code.

Comment: @Name, you should edit your question.  But note that providing a MCVE typically does not involve dumping all your code on us.  Follow the handy hyperlink that shmosel provided if you are uncertain of the concept or of how to go about preparing an MCVE.